# R to scale the y-axis to fit the loess curves

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to  reduce the scale of the Y-xis according to the loess function from ggplot2, even if it means that some raw points will not be displayed.

the problem is that I do not know beforehand what will be the maximum value of the loess function. All I have is the various raw data sets, and sometimes some of these data set can have high peaks once in while and therefore those are squishing all my loess curves to the bottom of the graphs, whereas I care more about the display of the loess curves than the display of the raw data (but these raw data must be displayed, at least those which are near the loess curves)

With this example, the blue loess line never goes higher than 2, while there are many point between 2 and 3; so typically, I want the top of the Y-axis to be 2 and ditch those extreme raw points.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(34)
n <- 200
X <- runif(n)*8
Y <- sin(3*X) + cos(X^2) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.5)

myData <- data.frame(X,Y)
fit <- loess(Y~X,data=myData)
myData$pred <- predict(fit)

ggplot(myData, aes(X,Y))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(method="loess", se=F, size=3)+
  geom_line(aes(X,pred),colour="yellow")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, just add a `coord_cartesian` call

```
ggplot(myData, aes(X,Y))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(method="loess", se=F, size=3)+
  geom_line(aes(X,pred),colour="yellow") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(min(myData$pred)-.1, max(myData$pred)+.1))
```